# Problem with "when and otherwise" condition

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

I will let the code do the explanation.

Dataweave gives errors:

> Unable to resolve reference of when
>
> Unable to resolve reference of otherwise

Input Message: An array of objects. Though I have given only 1 object here.

```
[{
    "Field1" : 12345,
    "field2" : 10
}]
```

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map {
"test" : $.Field1 when $.field2 >= 1 otherwise ""
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nadeem there is no `<expression> when <condition> otherwise <expression>` in DW 2.0.  Use `if (condition) <then_expression> else <else_expression>` instead.

So your code will be as follows:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = [{
    "Field1" : 12345,
    "field2" : 10
}]
---
data map {
    test : if  ($.field2 >= 1) $.Field1 else ""
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I should really look into the differences between DW 1.0 and 2.0 especially with regards to conditional statements.